# JavaScript: dynamically changing values of data range rule

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have an input field that either allows negative and positive numbers, or only positive numbers based on a value of a select.

When changing the value of the select option, I'm trying to modify the rule of the input field like this:

```
const id = '#myId';
$(id).attr("data-val-range-min", -10000);
removeRules(id);
addRules(id);
$(id).change(); // trying to trigger the validation of the rule
```

The `removeRules` is a function:

```
let removeRules = function removeRules(field) {
    $(field).rules('remove');
}
```

And so is the `addRules`:

```
let addRules = function addRules(field) {
    let $field = $(field);
    
    if ($field.attr("data-val-required")) {
        $field.rules("add", {
            required: true,
                messages: {
                    required: $field.attr("data-val-required")
                }
        });
    }
    
    if ($field.attr("data-val-number")) {
        $field.rules("add", {
            number: true,
                messages: {
                    number: $field.attr("data-val-number")
                }
        });
    }

    if ($field.attr("data-val-range")) {
        $field.rules("add", {
            range: [$field.attr("data-val-range-min"), $field.attr("data-val-range-max")],
                messages: {
                    range: $field.attr("data-val-range")
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I change the select in the UI, the `data-val-range-min` attribute is set correctly, but the rule is not reapplied.

Only when I manually click into the input-field and deselect it again, the rule is applied...

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only when I manually click into the input-field and deselect it again, the rule is applied...

There's a validation trigger you expect that isn't part of the plugin.

By default, this plugin triggers validation on:

- `onfocusout` - when you leave an element
- `onkeyup` - when you're typing inside a text box
- `onclick` - interactions with radio, checkbox, and select

Adding and removing the rules though is not enough... you'll also need to force a validation test after adding or removing the rule.

Simply call the `.valid()` method on the element or form when you want to programmatically force validation.  Since your OP contains zero HTML markup or working demo, I cannot be more specific with a solution.